# Convert XSD documentation into DocBook

Tags: xsd, docbook, xslt-tools

I've been looking for a template to achieve this. Apparently, only commercial applications, such as [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) can do that.

Is there any free tool that can do it? Or at least it would be great to have a base template to customize instead of writting it from scratch.

Closest tip I found in SO is [not very promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation/237985#237985).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, OxygenXML has a free trial license that will not watermark your output in any way.
Probably the quickest way.
Still, I am a bit curious why Docbook in particular - it is an intermediary format not meant for end user  user consumption, I guess the idea is you want to then produce a nice looking PDF and HTML out of that? If that's the case, not a bad plan.
Also it's not a whole lot of work to write your own XSL stylesheet to do that, you just need to map:
`complexType` and `simpleType` and `element` to db:section `xs:name` to `db:title` and `xd:annotation` to `para` then you can process this with free tools like saxon and docbook toolkit.

Comment: Your guess was right, using DocBook to get PDF & HTML ot of it. I got by with a custom XSL stylesheet. But things get fuzzy when you have complex/populated schema structures or thigs ike ´xs:choice´.