# Adding stylesheet to Schema

Tags: java, html, xml, stylesheet

I have a XML schema (.xsd) for my java web service, I added annotations to my file for documentation.

I have read that I can easily make the schema self-documenting by adding a stylesheet to it if I have annotations.

Anyone knows what does that mean and how can I do that? What kind of stylesheet, how and where can i add that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation

Comment: tnx looks good I am checking now

Comment: why do I need to use command line tools and XSLT? I just showed the xs3p.xsl to my schema and when I open it with firefox it looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two tools listed here:

http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema

one called xsddoc and one called XSDDoc (!)

I've come across others but can't locate them right now.