# XSD documentation as a part of build process

Tags: xml, maven, xsd

I've got multiple XSD files describing a schema. I'd like to generate a human readable documentation as a result of a build process.

The XSD is maintained and review within repository (gitflow) and commiting the documentation makes the repository cluttered. I'd like to generate human readable HTML during the build process (maven / gradle / ant build or simple CLI interface)

Found this post [How to convert xsd to human readable documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation) and [DocFlex/XML Maven plugin](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/maven.php) seems interesting but I can't believe that's the only one.

Any helpful tips on that?

Comment: Further research: oxygen XML has command line tools: http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/17.0/ug-editor/#topics/documentation-XML-Schema-command-line.html which generates desired HTML files. Still it's not integrated with build tools in any way (all manual work)

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer (and accept it), to make it easier to see this solution and to know that you consider the question answered and resolved.

Comment: Thx for tip. Done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with Oxygen Editor `schemaDocumentation.sh` script wrapped in gradle build.

My `build.gradle` so far looks like this - and I suspect it's still work in progress. It does it's job, HTMLs get generated to `build/generated-html` folder, but it requires oxygen to be installed in `OXYGEN_HOME` bath (with license included). I may fix it someday in the future

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ext {
    generatedDir = new File(buildDir, "generated-html")
}

def OXYGEN_HOME = "/opt/java/oxygen"
def schemaFiles = ["page", "metadata"]

schemaFiles.each { pageName -> 
    task "${pageName}SchemaTask"(type: JavaExec) {
        mkdir generatedDir

        classpath = files([
            "$OXYGEN_HOME", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/classes", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/oxygen.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/oxygenDeveloper.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/fop.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/batik-all-1.7.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/xercesImpl.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/xml-apis.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.0.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/icu4j.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/saxon.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/saxon9ee.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/log4j.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/resolver.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/oxygen-emf.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.3.5.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/fluent-hc-4.3.5.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/httpmime-4.3.5.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar", 
            "$OXYGEN_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar"
        ].toList())
        main = 'ro.sync.xsd.documentation.XSDSchemaDocumentationGenerator'  
        jvmArgs = ["-Djava.awt.headless=true"]
        args = ["schema/${pageName}.xsd", "-format:html", "-split:location", "-out:$generatedDir/${pageName}.html"] 
    }   
}

task schema(dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.endsWith("SchemaTask")}) {
}

defaultTasks 'schema'
```

I've documented the whole approach to build docs from XSD in the build process in this post http://jakub.marchwicki.pl/posts/2015/08/26/get-your-xsd-docs-as-build-process/