# How to turn XSD files into documentation file

Tags: xml, xsd

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to convert xsd to human readable documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation)
>   [Formatting XSD scheme for peer review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202049/formatting-xsd-scheme-for-peer-review)

I have a XSD file that includes xsd:annotation elements which contains a xsd:documentation element

```
<xsd:element name="CompanyId" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>The name of the company.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="40"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

How can I get the schema into a file (doc, spreadsheet, etc.) that would allow non-tech people to look at the contents of schema to better understand what data is available?

I want then to see that the field CompanyID contains "The name of the company." as shown in the xsd:documentation.  It would even be nice to see the length is up to 40 characters.

Comment: Why I am not able post an answer for this question?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the schema for the XML namespace at

http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd

When you view it in a browser, it is displayed using a client-side XSLT stylesheet; you can use the same stylesheet to browse your own schemas. The stylesheet is at

http://www.w3.org/2008/09/xsd.xsl

You could, of course, adapt it to your needs rather than using it directly.

**Note:** when you click on the first link above, be patient. W3C deliberately delays the response to requests for commonly-used files like this, to encourage applications to maintain a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use an xslt converter to some documentation format like this one : http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/

See also : [How to convert xsd to human readable documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation)

To use it you need an xslt application. If you're using Visual Studio (whatever the version), open the xs3p file in the IDE, then go in the menu : XML->Run (or something similar), it will ask for an input file and you will provide the xsd file. Once finished you'll get a file that is a XHTML file (so you might want to rename it) and you can open it in a browser. As pointed in the xs3p page, the documentation should like there : http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/examples/XMLSchema.xsd.html

If you don't have Visual Studio available, you can find other xslt processors easily on your platform.