# Automatically generate graphical documentation for XSD like XmlSpy does

Tags: xsd, continuous-integration, xmlspy

I would like to generate a graphical documentation of some XSD files (XML schema definition).
I know, there [are a few projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533257/4417811) that do a good job generating a textual documentation. But I use XmlSpy and I really love the tree that I get when I click on "print".

I would like to generate this automatically on a continuous integration server.
The question is: how can I get this scripted? I found a [forum post](http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1000002328) that sais "it's possible", but I don't have a clue where to start.

EDIT: the focus here is doing it from the command line rather than having a graphical editor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to visualize an XML schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486758/how-to-visualize-an-xml-schema)

Comment: @Abel: I guess, yes, I missed that question in my attempts to search for an existing question. I don't understand that question well enough on whether automation was the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- You may like [Xsdvi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsdvi/), which converts an input XSD into an SVG diagram like [this one](http://xsdvi.sourceforge.net/ipo.svg) (which I think is a logical choice: it's an XML to XML conversion). It is simple to use and its output can be rendered to any scale, it is SVG after all.
- This tool was mentioned in [this off-topic and deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473295/open-source-tool-to-generate-diagrams-from-xml-schema-documents/9339653#9339653) (requires 20k+ rep to view). And there's [XSDiagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram), check it out.
- Apparently, [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) can be used for this, as [this post shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305151/111575), which is free for registered users.

I have not tried any of these, I'm happy with what [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com) provides. Try them out. Be aware that asking for tools is typically off-topic on StackOverflow, though continuous-integration is not (hence I decided to answer anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stylesheets from the [XS3P](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xs3p/) project. You can apply them using a standard XSLT transformation engine (Saxon...).

Comment: The example outputs show a textual output. That is not what i am looking for.

Comment: It is HTML. But maybe not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Abel for pointing me to [XSD Diagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram). Since version 1.0 this program can also write the annotations into the generated image.

I am using it in the following way now:

```
XSDDiagramConsole.exe -o picture.png -r rootnode -d -y -e 10 schema.xsd
```